# Practical Examples of BSP based polygon triangulation

Tags: 3d, triangulation, bsp-tree

Anyone can point to a resource with code example on generating triangles out of polygonal shape using BSP trees approach ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entire C source code in the book Graphics gems 5, chapter III.5 entitled "A walk through BSP trees" here: http://books.google.it/books?id=8CGj9_ZlFKoC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=bsp+graphics+gems&source=bl&ots=yAbwNDYyIE&sig=412Xr8VfNdcN-nhNStCeX7wUyfU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fssfT7-ZF6Hf4QTuleizDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=bsp%20graphics%20gems&f=false

Comment: Unfortunately it deals with partitioning of the polygons and not their triangulation.This type of BSP is pretty trivial.Thanks for input anyways.

Comment: Ok I figured it out alone. Some experiments with a classical BSP tree helped.